# RC Filter Questions

Tags: capacitor, frequency, circuit-analysis

I am reading about RC circuits, and I have three questions, and since they are all related to RC circuit, I posted them together.

First question:
I read that with RC circuits we tend to use Current Sources and not voltage sources?
Could someone please explain why this is the case, and what would happen if we use voltage source?

Second question:
I usually dealt with FIR filters in digital domain, which tend to have linear phase response, which are advantages and will not cause any group delay. However, I noticed that RC circuits do not have linear phase response !! Is this something to our advantage in analog circuits (probably not)! If not, then, how we do take care of this?

Third question:
Could someone please explain in the simplest words, why do we care about the fact that current leads voltage? How is this used in practice? The only thing that I can get out of it is that there will not be any power dissipation, but other than that how does knowing that voltage leads current or current leads voltage make a difference in circuit design?

Comment: First question - no that is not true - RC filters are used without particular reference to the type of source. 2, it's not an advantage but in most cases it's not a disadvantage - it depends what you're trying to do. 3 - current leading or lagging voltage is not the "end" result usually, it's just the natural way RC filters happen to do "their stuff".

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you speak too generally of "RC circuits". Are you meaning a first-order circuit with only one capacitor? If so, where's this capacitor relative to the resistor and the source? How are they connected?

You have to be more specific if you want useful responses.

So, from now on, I assume you're speaking about a circuit like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUEgwt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

1) You can use whatever you want as source. But depending on the actual structure it may be nonsense. For instance, if you use a current source in the above circuit, this will make the resistor superfluous and the capacitor voltage will be simply proportional to the integral of the current source.

2) Depends on the application. If you have nonlinear phase you'll have phase distortion applied to your signals. According to Lipschitz et al., "On normal music or speech signals phase distortion appears not to be generally audible, although it was heard with 99% confidence on some recorded vocal material.". On the other side, if your application is not audio (i.e. video) this phase distortion can be of paramount importance and has to be kept under control. In those cases there are some kind of analog filters (notably Bessel ones) that have a phase response that is practically linear in the passband.

3) The "current leading voltage" concept only applies if you are working in sinusoidal steady state. For other waveforms different of the sinusoid it may not have sense at all. And in SSS the current leading voltage can be useful in some applications, and totally irrelevant in others.